# Ajax calls using PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to build a simple sign up form using AJAX and PHP. On submitting the form the submit_create_user_form() function is called.

This AJAX function calls ajax_calls.php page.

```
function submit_create_user_form(){
    var u = document.getElementById("org_name").value;

        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                var result =xhttp.responseText; 
                //status.innerHTML=xhttp.responseText;
                if(result==="Successful"){
                    //window.scrollTo(0,0);
                    document.getElementById('main').innerHTML ="An activation link has been sent to the new user's E-mail ID";
                }
                else
                    status.innerHTML="Some error Occurred!!";
            }       
          }
          xhttp.open("POST", "ajax_calls.php", true);
          xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

          xhttp.send("q="+u);


}
```

ajax_calls.php echoes "Successful" which is checked with xhttp.responseText in the above code snippet. 
Even then the output is "Some error occured."

ajax_calls.php:

```
if( isset($_POST["q"]) ){
    echo "Successful";
}
```

could someone help with this? Thanks!

Comment: Try using just a double equal check : `result=="Successful"`

Comment: Also, put curly braces around your else statement.

Comment: @RaphaëlVigée I have already tried using it. No change.

Comment: @devlincarnate Why? That's not needed.

Comment: for one, it's bad style not to have the braces.  for two, you're having a problem in that part of your code.

Comment: @ RaghavMotwani Do a `console.log(result);` just before the check.

Comment: @devlincarnate No change after putting curly braces.

Comment: @RaphaëlVigée It shows "Successful".

Comment: @RaphaëlVigée Actually it is "

Successful". I don't know How that extra space is coming. How to rectify it?

Comment: Strange... Add curly braces as suggested by @devlincarnate, and then put a `console.log` in each case of the check.

Comment: Oh you have an extra space ! That changes everything !

Comment: Use `result.trim()` in your check.

Comment: @RaphaëlVigée I have used trim(). No effect. Actually the console is showing                                                                                                    "----------blank line----------------------------------------------------------Successful"

Comment: Could you create a JSFiddle with your code ?

Comment: does JSFiddle support PHP?

Comment: @RaphaëlVigée  Also, I think the console output is right. I have tested it for other (working) AJAX script. The browser (Mozilla firefox) is showing console.log() in same format.

Comment: No, I would just want a JSFiddle of the JS to try everything I wanna try.

Comment: @RaphaëlVigée http://jsfiddle.net/ymsn1vaz/

Comment: I meant a functional JSFiddle that I can test.

Comment: @RaphaëlVigée http://jsfiddle.net/ymsn1vaz/1/ It is functional. You will have to create a PHP file with the code I have written above. It should work at your end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94262/discussion-between-raghav-motwani-and-raphael-vigee).

Comment: From the comments it seems like PHP is adding a blank line before the "Successful" output. This is probably because you have a blank line before `<?` in your PHP script. PHP will output anything not inside `<? ?>`, including whitespace.

It is very weird that `result.trim()` would not work for you. It should. Please check with `if(result.trim()==="Successful"){` again.

Answer (score -1):

This is a `jQuery` code

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
        var u=$('#org_name').val();
        $.post("ajax_calls.php",{q:u},function(data,message,xhr){
                                if(message==='success'){
                                    $('#main').text(data);
                                }
                            });

    });
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem in your code is:

you didn't declared `xhttp` add this code :

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Comment: I have declared xhttp as a global Identity. without that declaration, it would haven't even run.

Comment: just add the code an refresh your page i think it will be work

Comment: Tried doing it. I have now define local var xhttp, refreshed. No change.

Comment: Do this 'var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();'